# What is the best way to open and close a file without the `using` keyword

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to c#. In Python you have the option of either using the `with` keyword, or simply calling `f = open('filename')` and `f.close()`. Is there a c# equivalent to the later?

I'm avoiding using `using` because I'm trying to write bindings for a language which doesn't have a syntactic equivalent. I was hoping to write a class which had a `open()` and `close()` methods, and keep it as 1:1 as possible.

Comment: What's wrong with using `using` ?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to avoid using?

Comment: Use `try`, `catch`, and call `streamReader.Close(); streamReader.Dispose();` in a `finally` block.

Comment: @dvo That is **literally** what using does.

Comment: The [documentation for the `using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) shows exactly what the syntax is short for...

Comment: There are cases where you can't use `using` because you need the object alive after you leave a specific block of code, so I understand the question.

Comment: I edited the question to add more detail.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: At this point, you implement the Dispose pattern into whatever class keeps the undisposed reference.

Comment: @Christopher I know :) I think @Jones just doesn't know that `.Dispose()` exists.

Comment: The details just made the question even more unclear. It seems you want to reimplement `FileStream`. You can use the same pattern: it also has a `Close` method, which just calls its `Dispose` after all. So calling its `Close` at the end is basicly the same as putting it into a `using` block.

Comment: @Christopher You're correct. That's why I use `using`... But question asks how to do the equivalent. That's it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using is the best way. Also the only one that is remotely reliable and adviseable. You should avoid spliting up the creation and disposing of resources.

And it is little more then shorthand for a try/finally, null-check, dispose.

Indeed the [example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) has this:

```
using (var font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

Which is (almost) equivalent to this:

```
{
  var font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try
  {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
  }
  finally
  {
    if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: The main point here that answers the question is that `f.Dispose()` is the C# equivalent to `f.close()`in Python. The `using` statement just calls `.Dispose()` for you.

Comment: I can't use `try`/`catch` either. Are you saying that `.Dispose()` is safe to use?

Comment: @Jones `using` just calls `Dispose()` for you. So yes, you can call `Dispose()` yourself if you need to.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Erm, that's not quite the whole story. `using` _guarantees_ that `Dispose` will be called, regardless of whether there was an exception; calling `Dispose` directly, care would need to be taken in how the code around the `Dispose` call was written.

Comment: @KennethK. Yes, of course. If you're going to do it yourself, you need to make sure it gets called regardless of what happens or you'll end up with a memory leak.

Comment: @Jones A finally block will run, taht is it's most important property. It will run if the programm normally leaves the block. If it leaves due to an exception. Or even if you step out of the block using return. Using is just a shorthand for that try/finalize block and all that code.

Comment: @Jones You do **not** what to split up the creation and disposing of any unmanaged resource. create, use, dispose - all in the same block. Ideally using a using block. Redesign your programm rather then risk having to contratict that pattern.

Comment: @Jones There is one rare case where you can violate that rule. But that is advanced stuff and requires properly implementing the Dispose pattern. As you are clearly a beginner, I advise towards just a minor redesign of your application.